# How would humanity react if aliens relocated humanity and then decided to bring humanity back a week later

Tags: internal-consistency, aliens, culture

I remember once in history class, we were taught about the whole stigma that during the United States early years, European Americans would take Native American lands and put them in preserves. I then joked on the idea if an alien species for whatever reason, would just come to earth and relocate humanity as a form of historical Karma. Well turns out I wasn't the only person who would think of this idea, and that's exactly what happened within the plot of the movie *Home*

In the Movie, for a ridiculous reason, an alien species known as the boov decide to relocate ALL of humanity to preserves located in Australia in a place known as humanstown.  there each family would be given basic ownership of houses grouped up in circular batches.(Probably to make sure different cultures would not be too off to one another). And all the humans were given an adequate supply of basic needs and entertainment. In this "Town" The people don't have to work on any jobs, need to be paid, worry about civil protection, or have to farm their own food, It's all done by the aliens. Information like news and what's going on behind other batches more likely would not be shared publicly. All humans within the preserve are told that they will be living in these preserves for forever, and that moving to different other preserves is either physically impossible or illegal.  Meanwhile the rest of the boov take all of human housing and property and live in it themselves.

As to ensure enforcement, the boov would more likely do everything they can to distract humanity from thinking about there past home, and consider acts of disrespect or hostility as "mistakes". and if seven mistakes are made to a specific human. They could simply erase them, or "poof" them off of existence. If this rule of enforcement was done to themselves, it's more likely they would do the same to other species.

Here is an image of Humanstown just to get an idea of scale.
[image]

by the end of the movie, most of the the aliens decided to leave the earth and live on the moon instead, and relocate humanity again back to their initial homes.

So the question is, how would different Nationalities, Religions and different groups of people REALLY react in such a situation if they were sent to these centers? and if they did bring all 7+ billion people back to their exact homes, would all the world's nations, businesses and jobs be able to function back into their pre-alien selves? If so, how long would it take? would the world really accept these aliens to their own societies? If not, would they care if they stayed on the moon and agreed not to interfere with them again? Or would they simply in fear reverse engineer there technology and eventually go to war with them?

A Few Handwaves

1. No biological or language barriers. They change themselves to fit earth and vaccinate all of humanity and its wildlife by gassing the atmosphere.
2. The World's military doesn't detect them on time to stop them or warn anyone about the invasion.
3. Somehow, they have enough supplies and labor to support ALL human needs and a few wants. The best way that this could possibly be justified is that aliens have been living on a moon sized interstellar ship for several years, so they more likely have the technology to easily create food in huge amounts to sustain the population, same can go for creating 'Human food'.
4. The Aliens catch ALL of humanity in about an hour. same amount of time it took for them to bring them back.

The Scenario doesn't really have to go like it is in the film.
A situation like this would not even be close to being something realistically aliens would want to do to a primitive civilization. Even if they had a freakish desire to take Earth-land, they could've easily put them all in simulations, though it is interesting that they at least CARE about the life of humans unlike most fictional aliens in film.

But still, it's interesting to see how a situation like this could go down.

Comment: ...and they manage to fit seven **billion** people into Australia?

Comment: @nzaman Australia have 7,692,024 km2. It would be around 910 people/km². Macau have a population density of 21,411/km2. Other cities like Monaco and Hong Kong have also quite big population density. Even some countries like Bangladesh (1,106/km2) have a bigger population density. It would be crowded, there is lot of issues like food, but you **can** fit seven billion people into Australia

Comment: @nzaman, if humanity lived as densely as they do in Manhattan, [they could all live in New Zealand](https://www.fastcompany.com/3016331/think-the-world-is-crowded-you-could-fit-the-entire-human-race-in-new-zealand).  That's not the problem.  The problem is the square acreage needed, the transport system needed, the oil fields needed, etc., just to feed them.  We need to suspend all that disbelief to answer the question.

Comment: I guess the answer will depend largely if, as in the movie you cited, the aliens will stay on the moon or will totally leave never to be seen again?

Comment: 'Humanity' is made up of seven-and-then-some billion individuals, so reactions will be all over the spectrum. Some folks will be angry, some will become depressed, some won't care, some will see opportunity. The collective response of humankind depends upon whatever kind of leadership develops in humanstown, which seems a matter of opinion.

Comment: This question is up for reopening due to an edit, but the edit does nothing to limit, narrow, or improve the question.  In fact, it underscores the fact that the question is probably too broad (but it tickled my funny bone, so I answered it anyway).

Comment: Just to clarify, do you actually mean 1 week or some longer period of time? It sounds like it was longer than a week in the film.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**If you hand wave everything, like how to feed them, how to deal with sewer and garbage for just one week, how to water them, and all the supporting infrastructure needed for all that (the biggest of which is transportation, which needs oil and metal and machinery and the beat goes on and on and on...)...**

And that's a LOT to swallow, BTW.

- The psycological scaring caused by the overwhelming evidence that we are neither alone in the universe nor in the slightest way capable of defending ourselves from our new neighbors would cause a fair number of people to curl up on their sofas and either sicken or die from starvation.
- The psycological scaring caused by FoxNews, CNN, and every other news service subsequently broadcasting every conceivable aspect of the most "affecting" event ever to have been and ever to be in human history would cause more people to curl up on their sofas to sicken or die.  You can bet the news programs wouldn't let the subject go for weeks if not months.
- I'm not at all sure what the Australians would do if the aliens failed to clean up after themselves.  A substantial portion of their nation and continent would suddenly no longer be in its natural state.  I could imagine that having environmental and ecological consequences, afecting everything from wildlife to the weather.  Not to mention you'd have criminals claiming housing groups for their syndicates.  Australia would become the outback in a way neither man nor God ever intended.
- Anybody still sane enough to think would panic, demanding answers and assurances from govenments world-wide.  This would lead to two things (at least).  (a) Defense spending on a scale that would make the most Illuminati-crazed conspiracy nut's head explode and (b) people just like the people the Illuminati-crazed conspiracy nuts are afraid of stepping into positions of power to take personal advantage of the world-wide instability.  It would be a sociopath's dream.  And we're talking real end-of-the-world stuff here, cats and dogs living together... mass hysteria!  (I love that movie...)  By the time people started to realize their psyches were no longer in immediate danger (weeks, at least), the economic and political damage would be done — and it would be very hard to change.
- The really hopeful and good people among us hope and believe that in situations like this humanity will come together for mutual self-preservation, that it will erase national boundaries, dissolve racial insecurities, put a chicken in every pot, and stop the spread of gonorreah among teenagers.  What's more likely to happen is just the opposite.  Debilitating panic of all kinds in the days following this traumatic event will cause instability that could and probably would rip nations apart.  I could easily imagine the nation of Northern California kicking out all the Jews and promising "real change" while their people starve, all the while not telling the population there's no where near enough condoms for all the panic-justified teens.  But at least there will be enough Marijuana to keep the population relatively calm — for medical reasons.
- The population boom nine months later would be tragic in biblical proportions and would utterly overwhelm any national social-security-style protection in just under 70 years.
- Religion might see its greatest boon in history, maybe.  This one's a toughie.  Aliens would disprove most if not all religions.  But if you qualify as "religion" any philosophy meant to offer stability and comfort no matter what the cost to those bound together so, then you might see the single largest increase in new "religions" in human history.  And you can bet some of them would be more than willing to slough off the mortal coil to get them to the lunar surface as angels of light to join the welcoming aliens who did all this for our good, anyway.  The news media would have another month's worth of fodder and the Pastafarian membership would shrink for the first time in its history.  (Which is an unbelievably important issue since Pastafarianism's revelation that the lack of pirates is causing global warming will no longer keep alligators from protecting U.S. citizens from terrorist attacks.  You know they're doing their job because there havn't been any recent attacks.  I'm sure the government will hand me grant money to prove that I'm right.)
- Which means, of course, that defense businesses would boom, most luxury business would die, city infrastructure would suffer terribly due to employment shortages and the over-militarized *Purge*-watching public will think the coolest thing possible just happened.

The chaos and panic caused by so large an event over so short a period of time would be absolutely breathtaking.

*Of course, I could be completely wrong.*

Comment: I like how both "Scarring" and "scaring" work perfectly in your answer, so there's really no need to point out the typo.  Fox News would certainly be doing some "scaring".

Comment: @VBartilucci :-)  It was completely unintentional, I assure you!

Comment: `Australia would become the outback in a way neither man nor God ever intended.` Ahem, I think a little history lesson is in order... I mean, you do not say "Let's make Australia a beatiful place, let's send there all the criminals we can!".

Comment: @SJuan76 methinks you missed my point entirely.  But that's OK.

Answer (score 2):

### You are asking two questions:

1. How do humans react to knowing that an Alien race exists, lives nearby, and is so powerful that they can do anything to humanity at a whim and no one can stop them?
2. How do humans react to being forcefully relocated for reasons they don't understand, then afterwards are allowed to go home.

*To answer question 1.*

If you are in a scenario where your very survival depends on someone else and all the cards are in their hands and not yours, then what would a normal human being do? I think the answer is grovel. The humans will probably do whatever it takes to make the aliens happy because they don't want to be annihilated.

What will happen to the religions of the world? This will vary. I am sure someone will try to and explain that the aliens are really somehow part of god's plan, etc. Not much may change here except some really roundabout thinking to explain how the aliens fit into the current belief system.

*To answer question 2.*

The humans probably feel the same way that the Japanese in the USA did after World War 2. Angry, untrusting, offended, and like a foreigner in their own country, etc.

Answer (score 0):

## Basically everything about humanity would change

This is A Lot if new information for our puny human brains to take in so quickly. We just found out that

1: We are not alone, and aliens are 100% facts

2: We were just moved into a tiny area, so that aliens could live in our home

3: Then we go back to our homes

The psychological scarring would be immense, religions central belief structures would fall apart in etc. Programs like CETI would get huge bumps in funding, along with space exploration. Our species would be forever changed